# Grouping data.table by date sets

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a dataset that looks at transactions over a period of time and I'm trying to identify periods of transactions for each id. A basic example of the data would look like the example below.

```r
# id       date
# 1  2018-02-01
# 1  2018-03-01
# 1  2018-04-01
# 1  2018-05-01
# 1  2018-06-01
# 1  2018-06-01
# 2  2018-02-01
# 2  2018-03-01
# 2  2018-05-01
# 2  2019-01-01
# 2  2019-02-01
# 2  2020-06-12
# 2  2020-07-13
# 2  2020-08-11
```

What I want to be able to do is to group the data based on the proximity of the previous records date. So if there isn't a gap of more than 3 months for an `id` they would get the same group number. I've put together an example of what the desired outcome would look like.

```r
# id       date group
# 1  2018-02-01     1
# 1  2018-03-01     1
# 1  2018-04-01     1
# 1  2018-05-01     1
# 1  2018-06-01     1
# 1  2018-06-01     1
# 2  2018-02-01     1
# 2  2018-03-01     1
# 2  2018-05-01     1
# 2  2019-01-01     2
# 2  2019-02-01     2
# 2  2020-06-12     3
# 2  2020-07-13     3
# 2  2020-08-11     3
```

So I've tried to think about solutions using `rleid()` or using `shift()` to look ahead or behind but can't work out a suitable solution for this. I do wonder if some of it comes down to a lack of R vocabulary, so any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could do probably `setDT(df)[, group := c(0, cumsum((diff(month(date)) + diff(year(date)) * 12) > 3)) + 1]` or you if you don't really care about exact precision, could do just do `df[, group := c(0, cumsum(diff(date) > 90)) + 1]` or ```df[, group := c(0, cumsum(`units<-`(diff(date), "weeks") > 13)) + 1]```

Comment: The data >90 version works a treat. The cumsum is an absolute treat. I had tried an `ifelse()` but it wasn't quite working, but this is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increment the `group` value in each `id` when the current date is greater than 3 months from the previous date.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(group = cumsum((date %m-% months(3)) > 
                           lag(date, default = first(date))) + 1)

#      id date       group
#   <int> <date>     <dbl>
# 1     1 2018-02-01     1
# 2     1 2018-03-01     1
# 3     1 2018-04-01     1
# 4     1 2018-05-01     1
# 5     1 2018-06-01     1
# 6     1 2018-06-01     1
# 7     2 2018-02-01     1
# 8     2 2018-03-01     1
# 9     2 2018-05-01     1
#10     2 2019-01-01     2
#11     2 2019-02-01     2
#12     2 2020-06-12     3
#13     2 2020-07-13     3
#14     2 2020-08-11     3
```

---

In `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, group := cumsum((date %m-% months(3)) > 
                             shift(date, fill = first(date))) + 1, id]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = structure(c(17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 
17683, 17683, 17563, 17591, 17652, 17897, 17928, 18425, 18456, 
18485), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `ave` + `cumsum` + `diff`

```
within(
  df,
  group <- ave(as.numeric(date), id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(0, diff(x) > 30.42 * 3)) + 1)
)
```

which gives

```
   id       date group
1   1 2018-02-01     1
2   1 2018-03-01     1
3   1 2018-04-01     1
4   1 2018-05-01     1
5   1 2018-06-01     1
6   1 2018-06-01     1
7   2 2018-02-01     1
8   2 2018-03-01     1
9   2 2018-05-01     1
10  2 2019-01-01     2
11  2 2019-02-01     2
12  2 2020-06-12     3
13  2 2020-07-13     3
14  2 2020-08-11     3
```